# HAProxy forward header value in a custom header to backend

Tags: ssl, http-headers, x509certificate, haproxy, http-proxy

I am trying to forward certificate received in the header in `frontend` to a `backend` with different header name. However, the value is not forwarded. I am not able to identify in the documentation, how it should be done.

I am trying to do the following:

- receive header `ssl-client-cert` with the Base64 encoded certificate
- set new header `X-CERTIFICATE` with the value from `ssl-client-cert` header
- send the request with `X-CERTIFICATE` to backend

My current `haproxy.cfg` looks like this:

```
global
    log stdout format raw local0 debug

defaults
    log global
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client 1m
    timeout server 1m

frontend api_gateway
    mode http
    bind :8080

    http-request capture req.hdr(ssl-client-cert) len 64

    acl PATH_api path_beg -i /api
    
    use_backend core if PATH_api

    default_backend fe

backend fe
    mode http
    server fe fe-service:80

backend core
    mode http
    http-request add-header X-CERTIFICATE %[capture.req.hdr(0)]
    server core core-service:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
http-request add-header X-CERTIFICATE -----BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE-----\ %[ssl_c_der,base64]\ -----END\ CERTIFICATE-----\ # don't forget last space
```